# Is there a Latin word for a deadline?

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-latin, modern-life

Is there a Latin word for "deadline", a predefined point in time before which some assignment must be complete?
I have heard the literal translation *linea letalis*, but there are also words like *terminus* and *limes* that might be appropriate.
How would you express "deadline" in Latin and why so?
I prefer to have (something that can be used as) a noun, not a verbal expression.

Comment: Would _ultimatum_ do? Or a phrase with something like _ne plus ultra_ ?

Comment: @TomCotton I prefer to have a noun, so the phrase *ne plus ultra* does not qualify. It's a good phrase though, thanks for reminding me! I edited for clarity. *Ultimatum* might work, but I'm not familiar with that as a Latin word.

Comment: There is a verb _ultimare_, 'to come to an end', from which [English] ultimatum is derived.

Comment: How about [terminus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dterminus)? If time is implied by the context, I think it would suffice

Comment: @Rafael Sounds promising. It's one of the options I had in mind and therefore listed in the question. Explaining why that (or any other) word is suitable would make a nice answer.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Hahaha, I'm sorry. Why did I miss that?

Comment: Hmm. As I look through the literature, I see that *diēs indictus* seems to occur not as a *terminus* but as a single appointed date, which would suggest its "proper" use would be not for a deadline by which something was due but for a date *on* which it was due, neither before nor after being suitable. (Then of course there's the fact that it always seems to be a date set for a meeting.) So perhaps not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps (praestituta) ***summa dies***?

> *nisi mihi hodie attulerit miles quinque quas debet minas, sicut haec est praestituta **summa** ei argento **dies** ...*
>
> if the soldier doesn't bring me today the five minas he owes, since
>   today was the predetermined last day for the money ...
>
> Plautus, *Pseudolus*, act 1, scene 3

ADDIT: I just realised that since ***summa dies*** often means *last day* as in **death** (e.g. Lucan, *Civil War*, 8.29; Ovid, *Amores*, 9.27; Virgil, *Aeneid*, 2.324), this is perhaps a better fit for ***dead***line than I first thought!

Alternatively, ***dies praestituta*** might be a useful term.  Cicero seems to use it to mean an end date by which the delivery of corn must occur:

> “Deportatum habeas ante Kalendas Sextiles.” Deportabo igitur ... Sic
>   deportandi **dies praestituta** tollere cogebat ex area ...
>
> “Deliver your corn before the first of August.” I will then ... Thus,
>   **the** **fixing of a date/setting a deadline** for delivery compelled the removal of corn from the floor ...
>
> Cicero, *Against Verres 2*, 3.14.37